# Accidently forgot to cancel insurance Kaiser, refund possible?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I had a personal health insurance plan from Kaiser, but I forgot to cancel it when my workplace health insurance coverage (also from Kaiser) started, so for 2 months I was charged for 2 plans.  Is it possible to not pay the premium from my personal plan for the 2 months?

EDIT: So they charged me for 1 month and canceled the charge for the second month since I only used 15 day out of the month...

Comment: was the coverage through an employer?

Comment: 1 was personal 1 was from employer

Comment: was the coverage you want to cancel and refund from an employer?  You probably have a better shot at getting a refund if that is the case.

Comment: I mean either 1 is fine I don't really want to ask the HR but I can if there is a chance, but its already docked from my paycheck ..

Comment: Either one is very different that's why I'm asking the question.  The situation and universe of answers will be different if this is 1) you had individual coverage and moved to an employer plan, or 2) if you went from an employer plan to an individual plan, or 3) went from an employer plan to a different employer plan and inside those options which is the kaiser plan you want to cancel for a refund.

Answer (score 1):

Lets run though some situations.

- If you paid money for both policies, they are unlikely to refund the money for the personal policy. It isn't against the law to have multiple health insurance policies. It is just that in most cases they are redundant. But there are cases when one is prime and the other secondary and they can work together. Your situation would be the same as asking for a refund for any month when you didn't have a medical expense.

  You would have even less luck getting a refund from the employer policy. There are windows when you can join, and you did so. The risk is that they could ban you until the next open season.
- If you paid for the employer policy, but only have a bill from the personal policy you may have an even bigger problem. Even pre-COVID there were rules regarding delinquent insurance premiums. They can't cancel the policy if you miss the due date. Failing to pay the premium will eventually turn into a debt, that they can eventually try and collect. That debt collection could also hurt your credit score.

All this assumes that you didn't send any claims to them during the months in question. If you did, they will insist that they did their job.

I believe that you have learned an expensive lesson. I would cancel the personal policy today. And then ask for them to reduce what you owe or try and get a refund, you might get lucky.

Comment: only have a bill from the personal policy you may have an even bigger policy, you mean problem?

Comment: fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No refunds are available. Unpaid premiums will eventually cause your plan to be cancelled, retroactive to the last month that you paid for.

These unpaid premiums are not debt that you have to worry about. However, if you ever wish to enroll with Kaiser again, Kaiser can charge you as follows: "The consumer can be charged no more than one month of back premium payment in order for the health plan to be effectuated, if the consumer is enrolling in the health plan again."

https://insuremekevin.com/kaiser-cancels-coverage-of-covered-california-member-for-past-due-premiums-not-owed/

Comment: Are unpaid premiums relevant to this question?

Comment: OP's use of "I was charged" is ambiguous, so my answer covers both meanings: I was charged but did not pay (unpaid premiums) or I was charged and paid (no refunds).

Comment: From the title, "refund possible", I assumed both premiums were paid already and OP is trying to get their money back for one of them.

Comment: No I didn't pay premium but I assume in both cases is the same.

Comment: @bakaloo If you didn’t pay, what refund are you seeking?

Comment: @bakalolo I don’t know why you keep assuming all these very different situations are the same.